# Calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a javascript function to run a progress bar, here is my code:

```
<form  name="Calculation" method="post">

<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;">     </progress>

<span id="status"></span> 

<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1> 

<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="function   progressBarSim(al)"/>

</form>

 <script>
function progressBarSim(al) {

 var bar = document.Calculation.getElementById('progressBar');

  var status = document.Calculation.getElementById('status');

  status.innerHTML = al + "%";

  bar.value = al;

  al++;

  var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim(" + al + ")", 1);

    if (al == 100) {

    status.innerHTML = "100%";

    bar.value = 100;

    clearTimeout(sim);

    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');

    }
    }

   var amountLoaded = 0;


    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);

     </script>
```

The javascript function works on its own but I need to run it when the button is pressed and nothing happnes when I press the button "Press me".! any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: `onclick="progressBarSim()"`, however what are you passing as the argument you have in your function? Also `document.Calculation` is incorrect. Use `document.getElementById('progressBar')`

Comment: Calculation is the name of the form

Comment: And there's no need at all to use it as you are using getElementById to reference the ID of your element.

Comment: OK, I removed it but it did not solve my problem. The press button still does not work. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function in "onclick", instead of writing "function progresBarSim()". Also, "document.Calculation.getElementById" produces a js error, you should write "document.getElementById". Try this:

```
<form  name="Calculation" method="post">

<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;">     </progress>

<span id="status"></span> 

<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1> 

<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="progressBarSim(0)"/>

</form>

 <script>
function progressBarSim(al) {

 var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

  var status = document.getElementById('status');

  status.innerHTML = al + "%";

  bar.value = al;

  al++;

  var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim(" + al + ")", 1);

    if (al == 100) {

    status.innerHTML = "100%";

    bar.value = 100;

    clearTimeout(sim);

    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');

    }
    }

   var amountLoaded = 0;


    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);

     </script>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But why the argument is zero?? progressBarSim(0) instead of progressBarSim(al)

Comment: Another question, the progress bar runs when I refresh the page. I want it to ONLY run when I press the button. Is is any way to correct this?

Comment: Then don't call the function when the page loads (e.g. `progressBarSim(amountLoaded);`). I highly suggest you read some introduction to JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: The zero argument means the progress bar starts from zero percent.
To not let it run on page refresh, do what j08691 suggests and delete these lines:
   var amountLoaded = 0;
   progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
Learning some basic JavaScript will help you a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="function   progressBarSim()"/>` 
with

```
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="progressBarSim()"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, and yes there is one argument al that should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled around with the code and changed few stuff, try the following code:

```
<form  name="Calculation" method="post">

 <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>

 <span id="status"></span> 

 <h1 id="finalMessage"></h1> 

 <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="progressBarSim(0)"/>
</form>

<script>
 function progressBarSim(al) {
 var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
 var status = document.getElementById('status');
 status.innerHTML = al + "%";

 bar.value = al;
 al++;

 var sim = setTimeout(function(){ progressBarSim(al); }, 1);
 if (al == 100) {
    status.innerHTML = "100%";
    bar.value = 100;
    clearTimeout(sim);

    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onclick="function   progressBarSim()"
```

to

```
onclick="progressBarSim()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `function` like `onclick="ProgressBarSlim()"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onclick="function   progressBarSim()"` with `onclick="progressBarSim()"`

**Like this:**

```
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="function   progressBarSim()"/>
```

**After replaced**

```
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!" onclick="progressBarSim()"/>
```